# NonNull List Items with Lombok

Tags: java, lombok

I'm currently building a Java application and using Lombok annotations to reduce boilerplate. I'm running into problems, however, when using the `@Singular` and `@NonNull` annotations together. For example, let's look at the following example class:

```
@Builder
class Classroom {

    @Singular @NonNull
    private List<String> students;
}
```

I would like the @NonNull annotation to protect from adding `null` elements *singularly*, like so:

```
Classroom.builder()
    .student("Sally")
    .student("Joe")
    .student(null)
    .build();
```

However, even with the annotation, the `null` element is still added to the list when the `Classroom` object is built. Is there an easy way, using Lombok annotations, to mark singular elements as NonNull, or am I going to need to drop the annotations and implement that type of protection myself?

Comment: I presume the `@NonNull` annotation means that the `students` list itself cannot be null. Not that individual elements cannot be null.

Comment: I'm aware that the annotation means that the list can't be `null`; I was hoping it would also extend to the singular elements themselves as well.

Comment: Agree it would be nice to have the feature to specify `@NonNull` for elements _separately_ from the `Collection`/`Map`/etc itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Lombock documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/NonNull.html) :

> You can use @NonNull on the parameter of a method or constructor to have lombok generate a null-check statement for you.

So you have to put the `@NonNull` annotation on the parameter of the `student` method (in the builder class) and not on the private field `students` (in the Classroom class).

```
public student(@NonNull String name){
    students.add(name);
}
```